# How do I calculate the time remaining for my upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

In my **jQuery file uploader** I have the following available variables: `uploadedBytes`, `totalBytes` and `timeStarted`.

How do I caculate the time remaining for an upload using these variables? I came across a similar question that involved an `uploadSpeed` variable.

Can I deduce the `uploadSpeed` from these variables?   Or am I able to calculate time remaining using only those three variables?

Comment: Well.. the time it takes to upload depends on the speed, so you need that. You can not calculate it from the variables you have.

Comment: Would depend on one's network speed; if you said a message saying "*x mins based on a `2MB` line*"

Comment: @putvande you can give an approximation using the average upload speed .

Comment: the `uploadedBytes` changes during the upload?

Comment: @Frogmouth
Yes, `uploadedBytes` is called upon during upload progress and updated accordingly.

Comment: if it changes you can `setInterval` that every second calculates the approximate time to end of upload. - ex: in one second `uploadedBytes` is 500kb so your download speed is 500kb/s... with this data you can calculate the remaining time.

Comment: Here is a related article with a slightly different solution: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279682/jquery-file-upload-show-time-remaining/27711792#27711792

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that `uploadedBytes` is changing during upload.

-> Call this script when you know that the upload starts:

```
var timecontroller = setInterval(function(){
    timeElapsed = (new Date()) - timeStarted; // Assuming that timeStarted is a Date Object
    uploadSpeed = uploadedBytes / (timeElapsed/1000); // Upload speed in second

    // `callback` is the function that shows the time to user.
    // The only argument is the number of remaining seconds. 
    callback((totalBytes - uploadedBytes) / uploadSpeed); 
}, 1000)
```

-> When the file was fully uploaded, clear interval `timecontroller`:

```
clearInterval(timecontroller)
```

Pay attention that `timeStarted` must be a Date object.

Tell me if its work.
Thanks to @Stefano Sanfilippo - I use some of his script.

Comment: Had to rearrange it a little but it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You rock mate! :) Glad to have helped! - maybe you can add your change... :) if some find this quest and need the answer.

Comment: "pay attention: timeStarted must be a Data Object. " is it Date object?

Comment: The result of an instance: "new Date()".
Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: This is not the most correct answer. Imagine this scenario: You are uploading 1GB file, and the first 500MB you uploaded with maximum speed. Then in paralel you start uploading in another tab. The upload speed for your rest of 500MB has now been split in half. In this case the Remaining time is not correct, because it will still keep accounting for the full-speed which was in the firt part of the upload.

Comment: @besciualex That's your call. This is more like an average solution. You can change the code to support `chunks`. So you have to choose between a smooth average or an erratic estimation. When you hit certain percentages, you can simply reset your `timeElapsed` and the already downloaded bytes at that moment. That way you are always estimating on a more accurate timestamp.

Comment: @Eduard My above comment's purpose is to make peoples aware of this scenario and adapt to it (if they want). Now you gave them the solution too. :)

Comment: @besciualex is a good point. If you have some time you can add this scenario (with some code) to my answer :) you are welcome.